# How to use EXIST to improve speed in mySQL subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with this query below. It takes forever to complete the query.
I have been using describe to help me find best way to pull this data. But this is what I can come up with so far. But this take forever to pull just 1000 records . I would like to get some recommendations / suggestions on how to approve this issue ? I'm stuck.

I have read about "EXISTS" that I can use to improve subquery , but I am not quite understand how it would work in this situation.

I have already used primary keys as much as I could ( id , contact_id , flag_if ) => those ending with _id are all primary keys.

Thanks.

```
SELECT ac.id,
      acc.category,
      ac.value, 
      fg.*

FROM contact AS ac
JOIN application AS app ON app.id = ac.id
JOIN category AS acc USING (contact_id)

LEFT JOIN (SELECT af.name_short 
                ,att.value 
                ,att.flag_id
    FROM attribute AS att
        LEFT JOIN attribute_flag AS af ON af.flag_id = att.flag_id
        LEFT JOIN application app on 
                (       (att.level = 'customer' AND att.related_id = app.customer_id)
                        OR  (att.level = 'application' and att.related_id = app.id)
                                 )
        WHERE app.id IN  (001,002,003)
                ) fg on ac.value = fg.value

WHERE ac.id IN  (001,002,003)
```

== UPDATE == 
here is the result from explain query'

[image]

Comment: I don't see a way you can use `exists` here. You can use `exists` for uncorrelated subqueries.

Comment: @bernie what would you recommend me to do in order to improve this particular query.

Comment: What indexes do you have?

Comment: Please add output of query explanation: `EXPLAIN SELECT ac.id, acc.category...`.

Comment: value ,
category ,
contact_id ,
flag_id ,

Comment: @bishop I have update my question, and added explain as you recommended.

Comment: It feels like your subquery can be reorganized and built into a join, but I don't oversee it. Anyway, I would try the following composite index: `attribute(level, related_id, flag_id, value)`, maybe in a different order, `attribute(value, level, related_id, flag_id)`.